# Wireless Magic Keyboard with windows PC not connected after restarting Windows

Tags: keyboard, bootcamp, windows, bluetooth

After restring windows the connected keyboard does not work on my PC (Dell Laptop).

I have installed the bootcamp driver. What could be the cause of this? On my Mac with bootcamp I do not have the issue (same type of keyboard).

How does it work with Bootcamp but not with a Windows PC? What part is apple installing that we are missing on a PC if we install the Bootcamp drivers?

Comment: This might best be asked on SuperUser or elsewhere as it is about a PC keyboard that doesn't work on a PC. The Mac is incidental here and only a data point for further troubleshooting, "it works on a Mac in Bootcamp."

Comment: The difference is on a mac the bluetooth keyboard works in EFI before OS is loaded - you can press *alt* to get boot menu for example or type stuff in EFI shell. In Windows or Linux the driver is loaded as part of the OS so on your Dell it depends on whether the firmware supports magic keyboard or not.  Sounds like it doesn't but it should work after OS loads.

Comment: This is on topic here. I would say if OP wants it migrated we can to SU. It would also be fine to ask a general mouse troubleshooting question on SU if that’s desired. Let’s see if this gets answers here or Jessica asks for it to be migrated.